# Unused variables for storing calculations -- are they redundant and can I get rid?

Tags: java, benchmarking

I was creating a simple 'benchmark' program checking how many calculations a PC can do in 1 second, three times, then averaging and printing the result.

```
package benchmark;

public class Benchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + 1000;
        long index = 0;
        long index2 = 0;
        long index3 = 0;
        while (true) {
            double x = Math.sqrt(index);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now > endTime) {
                break;
            }
            index++;
            }
        while (true) {
            double y = Math.sqrt(index2);
            long now2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now2 > endTime) {
                break;
            }
        while (true) {
            double z = Math.sqrt(index3);
            long now3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now3 > endTime) {
                break;
            }
        }
            long total = (index + index2 + index3) / 3;
        }
        System.out.print(index + " loops per second on average.");
        }
    }
```

x, y and z variables are used here to store the result of Math.sqrt(index), and indexes 2 and 3.

However at no point in this program are the x, y and z variables called upon at all. Is there a way to remove them from the program?

Comment: just write `Math.sqrt(index)` instead of `double x = Math.sqrt(index);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove them, just call the method without storing the result, replace:

```
double x = Math.sqrt(index);
```

by

```
Math.sqrt(index);
```

Comment: Not sure why the tutorial book I'm using bothered to create x, y and z. I guess for clarity that there is a variable there, but seems to overly complicate matters!

Comment: Ahem. How come this is an approved answer? OP grossly oversimplifies benchmarking, and asks the wrong question to begin with. The entire calculation is redundant, whether you store it in the local variable, or not. I'll try to guess the "tutorial book" (which one, btw?) tries to store to local to make the computation *non*-redundant. But that will fail too. Please use JMH, or at least try to read and run this example: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_08_DeadCode.java

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev It's an accepted answer because as far as I can tell it answered the problem I had. I'm a beginner learning Java so I'm bound to ask the 'wrong' questions and to 'oversimplify' benchmarking. I'm not building a genuine benchmarking tool but trying to learn very basic steps about loops.

It wasn't accepted to belittle any other answer. I found Simone and Vlad's below very insightful too.

Comment: Sometimes *not* answering the wrong question is better than answering it and reinforcing OPs way of thinking about the issue. This is one of those cases. Which tutorial book you are using?

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev Sam's Learn Java in 24 Hours (don't worry I plan on spending longer than 24 hours learning...)

Answer (score 3):

A variabile uses space on the stack, and the relative push operation to write to the stack.

The compiler and/or the JIT (Just in time compiler) might (and usually will) remove those variables automatically, so having them or not having them will not make a difference if not in the first loops.

If you're mico-benchmarking you should always run the loop a few times (standard seems to be 10000 times) to warmup the code, and then re-run it again to measure real performance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this solution?

> package benchmark;
>
> public class Benchmark {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
>     long endTime = startTime + 1000;
>     long index = 0;
>     long index2 = 0;
>     long index3 = 0;
>     while (true) {
>         Math.sqrt(index);
>         long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
>         if (now > endTime) {
>             break;
>         }
>         index++;
>         }
>     while (true) {
>         Math.sqrt(index2);
>         long now2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
>         if (now2 > endTime) {
>             break;
>         }
>     while (true) {
>         Math.sqrt(index3);
>         long now3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
>         if (now3 > endTime) {
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>     }
>     long total = (index + index2 + index3) / 3;
>     System.out.print(total + " loops per second on average.");
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Also noticed that at the end I have System.out.print(index + "loops per second on average.");, rather than System.out.print(total ...).

Any idea why it won't let me change index to total? The long variable is created directly above.

Comment: "total" had a different scope and was not accessible from the System.out.print. Please check the edited code, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Also note, that index2 and index3 are never incremented and endTime is never recompouted, so the second and third while loop are only executed once anyway.